# How do you test whether a model has a given method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, shoulda

I would like to implement the method `User.calculate_hashed_password`. I'm trying to use the Shoulda testing library which works with Rails's built-in testing tools, so an answer related to Test::Unit would be just as good as one related to Shoulda (I think).

I'm trying to figure out **what** I need to test and **how** I should test it. My initial idea is to do something like...

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should 'Return a hashed password'
    assert_not_nil User.calculate_hashed_password
  end
end
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: What does 'calculate_hashed_password' do? Generates a hashed version of the 'password' attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to test that the method exists, just that the method behaves correctly.  Say something like this:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = User.new
  end

  should 'Calculate the hashed password correctly'
    @user.password = "password"
    @user.hashed_password = "xxxxx" # Manually calculate it
  end
end
```

(I don't use shoulda, so excuse any glaring syntax errors.)

That test will fail if the method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Otto; but as dylanfm noted, I use #respond_to to test for associations in RSpec.

```
it "should know about associated Projects" do
  @user.should respond_to(:projects)
end
```

Comment: I do that, too, just as a simple sanity check that I put the association line in the model class.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use `respond_to?`

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Object#respond_to?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000333) and [Object#try](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-object-try) in newer versions of Rails. If you're new to testing in general, definitely read through this [excellent guide on testing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing_rails_applications.html#_unit_testing_your_models).